# Should I create a folder structure in my Azure Blob Container?

Tags: azure, file, azure-blob-storage, media

We've decided to use Azure Blob Storage for containing our media files.
There are often between 100 - 18.000 files per "playable unit" (i.e. movie, music track, podcast episode etc). Each "unit" has a GUID, and is of some type.

I see 2 alternatives:

A)
No structure. All files are in base of container. The Guid is unique, so there is no overlap.

```
Examples of file name/uri:
238F580F-2D74-4C17-B237-CCD6D32F7279-movie-part_001
238F580F-2D74-4C17-B237-CCD6D32F7279-movie-part_002
C1A832BA-6B48-44AA-AC51-A2D7CD031708-podcast-part_037
```

B) Structuring them with fewer files per folder.

```
Examples:
movies/23/8F/58/0F/238F580F-2D74-4C17-B237-CCD6D32F7279/part_001
movies/23/8F/58/0F/238F580F-2D74-4C17-B237-CCD6D32F7279/part_002
podcasts/C1/A8/32/BA/C1A832BA-6B48-44AA-AC51-A2D7CD031708/part_037
```

1. Are there any performance benefits from structuring our files in folders? Is the getting/updating blobs equally fast? (We previously used an actual file storage, in which not having too many files per folder was important for lookup speed).
2. Any Maintanability or other benefits for my future development?

Comment: hard to say as we have no ideas about the road map and requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have lots of files, I will go with folder structure.

> 1. Are there any performance benefits from structuring our files in folders? Is the getting/updating blobs equally fast? (We previously used an actual file storage, in which not having too many files per folder was important for lookup speed).

Folder structure inside container is virtual, you will not see any performance changes with/without folder structure.

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
```

> 2. Any Maintainability or other benefits for my future development?

When you want to visualize/find movie file from Azure Storage explore it would be helpful.